# How do i trouble shoot a failed ajax return

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have some JavaScript that  calls a function to repopulate a drop down list. There are 2 calls that populate 2 different drop down lists. The both work fine in local Dev. On the server only one works. The one Errors out. I remote debugged and the call reaches the function and the function returns the proper results. Its after it leaves the function that the error occurs. The application is asp.net mvc 3 the server is windows server 2008 iis7.

How can i narrow down what is causing the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function getSects(abbr) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SectionSwitch", "Assets")",
        data: { abbreviation: abbr },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // var test = JSON.parse(data);
            //alert(test);
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.sectionNum + "\">" +      item.sectionname + "</option>";

            });

            $("#Asset_Section_SectionKey").html(items);
        }
    });
}

function getDivs(abbr) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("DivisionSwitch", "Assets")",
        data: {abbreviation: abbr},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data2) {
           // var test = JSON.parse(data);
            //alert(test);
            var items = "";
            $.each(data2, function(i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.DivisionKey + "\">" + item.DivisionDescription + "</option>";

            });

            $("#Asset_Section_Division_DivisionKey").html(items);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Asset_Section_Division_Department_DepartmentKey").change(function () {
        var abbr = $("#Asset_Section_Division_Department_DepartmentKey").val();

        getDivs(abbr);
    });

    $("#Asset_Section_Division_DivisionKey").change(function () {
        var abbr = $("#Asset_Section_Division_DivisionKey").val();

        getSects(abbr);
    });
});
</script>
```

Its the function getDivs that is throwing the error. Here are the functions:

```
 public ActionResult DivisionSwitch(int abbreviation)
    {

        var newdivision = from f in db.Divisions
                          where f.DepartmentKey == abbreviation
                          select f;

        return Json(newdivision);

    }

    public ActionResult SectionSwitch(int abbreviation)
    {

        var newsection = (from t in db.Sections
                          where t.DivisionKey == abbreviation
                          select new sectionInfo { sectionNum = t.SectionKey, sectionname = t.SectionDesciption });

        return Json(newsection);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your error properties on your ajax methods to take 3 parameters `(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` and alert the `errorThrown` and `textStatus`:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error, status: " + textStatus + " error: " + errorThrown);
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, I get Internal server error. Now i need to figure out what that means.

Comment: @mdarling Hmm that could be an indication that the URL is wrong. In the error function, also alert `"@Url.Action("SectionSwitch", "Assets")"` and make sure the URL is correct.

Comment: Its not a problem with the url. I ran remote debugging and could see that the function was triggered. Its after the  return that the problem occurs. Thanks though!

Comment: i figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mdarling Good stuff! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Set up an [error handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) and see what it has to say

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    console.log(jqxhr);
    console.log(exception);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,  i used one of the other answers, and was told it was an internal server error. Will your solution give me any more detail?

Comment: Look at the response with a tool like fiddler and see if it gives you any more info. Sounds like you should change the error handling on the server with the MVC3 framework.

Comment: thanks, i had just installed fiddler. I will check it out. It just seems odd that one call works and the other doesn't.

Comment: i figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The error part of your $.ajax can accept three parameters of type  `jqXHR`, `textStatus`,  `errorThrown`.

The first parameter is an object of type jqXHR, the other two are strings. You could use `jqXHR.responseText` to see the error.

```
$.ajax({ // Some settings
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        // or
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
```

According to jQuery web site, their example suggests following:

```
$.ajax({ // your settings

}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
    // Handle success 
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Handle error here
});
```

For more information have a look at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) and read the Depreciation section.

Comment: Thanks, three responses really quickly, i mentioned in another comment it just tells me its an internal server error.

Comment: i figured it out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the help but i decided to rewrite what was being returned similar to what the working call was returning. Apparently the server had a problem with what was being returned.

```
public ActionResult DivisionSwitch(int abbreviation)
{

    var newdivision = from f in db.Divisions
                      where f.DepartmentKey == abbreviation
                      select f;

    return Json(newdivision);

}

public ActionResult SectionSwitch(int abbreviation)
{

    var newsection = (from t in db.Sections
                      where t.DivisionKey == abbreviation
                      select new sectionInfo { sectionNum = t.SectionKey, sectionname = t.SectionDesciption });

    return Json(newsection);

}
```

I have now changed to code to this:

```
public ActionResult DivisionSwitch(int abbreviation)
    {

        var newdivision = (from f in db.Divisions
                          where f.DepartmentKey == abbreviation
                           select new DivisionInfo { DivisionNum = f.DivisionKey, Divisionname = f.DivisionDescription });

        return Json(newdivision);
}
```

I just created a new class to store  the result in and narrow it down to the two  feilds required.

```
     public class DivisionInfo
{
    public int DivisionNum { get; set; }
    public string Divisionname { get; set; }
}
```